# Gitlab with Let's Encrypt certificate: upgrade your ACME client to ACMEv2

Tags: gitlab, ssl-certificate

I had Gitlab installed on Ubuntu 14.04. It was failing to renew Let's Encrypt certificate. I have upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 and then apt-get update && apt-get upgrade but it seems that it didn't upgrade ACME client to v2 that would allow me to update a certificate. How can I update a certificate?

```
gitlab-cli renew-le-certs
```

results in:

```
letsencrypt_certificate[elenx.net] (letsencrypt::http_authorization
line 3) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::Unauthorized:
acme_certificate[staging]
(/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb
line 20) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::Unauthorized: Account
creation on ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a
version that supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430
for details.
```

Comment: Did you try `gitlab-ctl renew-le-certs` ?

Comment: Yes, an error is: letsencrypt_certificate[elenx.net] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 3) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::Unauthorized: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 20) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::Unauthorized: Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430 for details.

Comment: Please do not post additional info in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: You are right, I have added it to question.

Comment: While your are at it, you can as well format the error message correctly in a code block,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4614#note_232009029

> Interesting dilemma. We've upgraded the ACME client in !3420 (merged)
>   in GitLab 12.1, but you're blocked from upgrading until you can get a
>   successful reconfigure.

So you need to upgrade to gitlab >= 12.1

1. Turn off letsencrypt:  `nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
   a few pages down look for: `letsencrypt['enable'] = true` and set it to `false` then save
2. Upgrade to latest release of your major version 
   `apt-get upgrade gitlab-ee=11.11.8`
3. Run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
4. Upgrade to Gitlab 12  `apt-get upgrade gitlab-ee`
5. Run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
6. Reboot `sudo reboot`
7. Return `letsencrypt['enable'] = true` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
8. Run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
9. Run `gitlab-ctl renew-le-certs`

Comment: You might have to go to a middle-step version before 11.11.8. For example: i had to upgrade to 11.4.7-ee.0 first, and then 11.11.8. 
You can list available versions with: sudo apt list -a --upgradable

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. The steps mentioned by @Ryabchenko is perfect.

I am adding a few more steps.

- Remove the old certificates from **/etc/gitlab/ssl/** ( after step no 6 in @Ryabchenko 's answer)
- You are getting an error in lin 20. If someone get an error on line 25 which is

> RuntimeError: acme_certificate[staging]

then add following line in gitlab.rb

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {\n root /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/www/; \n}\n"
```

**Note**: I have mentioned the detailed steps here:  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4900#note_292031191